# Issue with LONGBLOBs in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, blob

I'm trying to insert LONGBLOBs to my database. Unfortunately when I click insert nothing is being inserted in the db. When I change the column type to BLOB everything is fine but the blob size capacityis too small so I really need LONGBLOBs. Using blob I can add only a 64kb file. Using longblob I can insert a file which is much larger. What's why I need to use LONGBLOB.  I'm using MySQLi and PHP. Could you help me out?

```
if($_POST && $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] > 0) {       
        $name = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
        $_SESSION['fileType'] = $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];

        $data = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
        //$data = addslashes($data);
        $ifImage = getimageSize($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']);
        $getAuthorID = $_SESSION['userID'];
        $_SESSION['ifImage'] = $ifImage;
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['ifImage'], true).'</pre>'; 

        $fp      = fopen($data, 'rw');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($data));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

        /*          SELECT FILE ID BY IT'S NAME          */
        $selectIDname= "SELECT fileID FROM files WHERE fileName = '$name'";
        $selectIDnameQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $selectIDname);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectIDnameQuery);
        $selectIDname = $row['fileID'];
        echo '<pre>ID: '.print_r($selectIDname, true).'</pre>';
        $_FILES['uploadFile']['fileID'] = $row['fileID'];

        /*           INCREMENT FILE ID          */
        $selectFileIDQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT fileID FROM filescontent ORDER BY fileID DESC LIMIT 1");
        $fetchFileID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectFileIDQuery);
        $incrementFileID = $fetchFileID['fileID'] + 1;

        /*          GET AND INCREMENT FILE VERSION          */
        $getVersionsObject = new File($_FILES['uploadFile']['fileID']);
        $fetchVersions = $getVersionsObject->getVersions();
        $fetchLastElement = end($fetchVersions);
        $incrementVersion = $fetchLastElement + 1;
        echo '<pre>Version: '.print_r($incrementVersion, true).'</pre>';

        /*          SELECT FILE NAME FROM DB          */
        $selectName = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT fileName FROM files WHERE fileName='$name'");
        $fetchName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectName);
        $fetchName = $fetchName['fileName'];

        if(!strcmp($name, $fetchName)){
            echo 'The file exists <br>';
            $insertIntoFilescontentObject = new File($_FILES['uploadFile']['fileID']);
            $insertIntoFilescontent = $insertIntoFilescontentObject->uploadContentIntoFilescontentFileExist($selectIDname, $incrementVersion, $content, $getAuthorID);  
        }
        else{
            echo 'The file does not exist'; 
            $insertIntoFilesObject = new File($_FILES['uploadFile']['fileID']);
            $insertIntoFiles = $insertIntoFilesObject->uploadContentIntoFiles($incrementFileID, $name, $getAuthorID);
            $insertIntoFilescontentObject = new File($_FILES['uploadFile']['fileID']);
            $insertIntoFilescontent = $insertIntoFilescontentObject->uploadContentIntoFilescontentFileNotExist($incrementFileID, $incrementVersion, $content, $getAuthorID);    
        }

        $mysqliErorr = mysqli_error($connection);
        echo '<br>'.$mysqliErorr.'<br>';
        //header("Location: listFiles.php");
    }
    else if($_POST && $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] == 0) {
        echo 'You have not chosen a file';
    }
}
```

Comment: I would actually advise against storing large files into a MySQL database. File systems are meant for handling files, and databases are meant for storing data. I would stick with that principle. Store the file in the file system and store the URL to the file path within the database. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy OK thanks for the advise but I would like to store the files in the database, so the problem with LONGBLOBs is still here